# Is my lemon tree dead?

Tags: lemons

[image: latest picture][image]

UPDATE, New picture added. I have trimmed the dead stems away and just over a week it's starting to look healthier and new growth is visible. My question now is, will these new green stems eventually become big ones like the one I cut off or will this tree no longer produce lemons? Cheers.

It's not that old, and it was doing well last year and gave me some nice lemons. Unfortunately, it was left out over the winter, I live in the UK. All the leaves have fallen and most of the branches are now like a fragile brown and white colour.

I have re-potted it and tried trimming it down a bit in the hope it will recover but I'm fairly new to this so any help will be appreciated. I'm just wondering if it's dead or if it can be saved. Picture below Thanks.

I have update the latest picture to this post, should I cut away the thick part and the smaller stems that don't have green stems where I have scratch the surface?

https://photos.app.goo.gl/xwBCAtm8977j2frJ9

Answer (score 1):

If it has green leaves, that part at least isn't dead. Gently scrape away the bark from the dead-looking bare stems. If you see green, the stems are still alive. If you don't see green, the stems are dead and can be cut back.

Comment: Can you see the picture in the link I posted?

Comment: @TrfcTrfc - Yes, the green bit is definitely alive. Test the bare stems as I suggested.

Comment: Thanks. Basically all bare stems same after scraping. The closer I get to the main part of the tree it then is green. Is it worth cutting back? Will it grow back? As it's 80% of the tree

Comment: I have update the original post with the picture once I scratched some of the stems. My worry is it seems the main stem is dead. Would this grow back if cut right back? Thanks for help

Comment: @TrfcTrfc - The main stem looks dead to me. If it's dead, it won't grow back. I would suggest cutting the main stem back to just above the green growth, and also cut off all the other dead bits.  Don't be discouraged. You have (a) learned your plant isn't winter hardy in the UK, (b) a lemon tree that is still alive, and (c) an interesting talking point.

Comment: Thank you for your input. If I could direct message you I would buy you a drink for your help. I shall do some chopping in the morning and give it till April next year to see if it grows back, if not I will then replace with a new. Thanks again and I've learnt something you are right 